# I want to make Tab bar like app store UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

[image]

I want the same color as in App Store. Gradient and background color and selected color and unselected color all the same.

```swift
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    tabBar.barTintColor = .clear
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.5)], for: .normal)
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.7)], for: .selected)
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        var appearance = tabBar.standardAppearance

        // Set a more transparent background with a blur effect
        appearance.backgroundEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .systemMaterial)

        // Set tab bar item colors
        setTabBarItemColors(appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance)
        setTabBarItemColors(appearance.inlineLayoutAppearance)
        setTabBarItemColors(appearance.compactInlineLayoutAppearance)

        // Set tab bar item badge appearance
        setTabBarItemBadgeAppearance(appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance)
        setTabBarItemBadgeAppearance(appearance.inlineLayoutAppearance)
        setTabBarItemBadgeAppearance(appearance.compactInlineLayoutAppearance)

        tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
    } else {
        // Fallback for earlier iOS versions if needed
    }
}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
private func setTabBarItemColors(_ itemAppearance: UITabBarItemAppearance) {
    // Set colors for normal and selected states
    itemAppearance.normal.iconColor = .systemGray
    itemAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.systemGray.withAlphaComponent(0.5)]

    itemAppearance.selected.iconColor = .label
    itemAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.label.withAlphaComponent(0.7)]
}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
private func setTabBarItemBadgeAppearance(_ itemAppearance: UITabBarItemAppearance) {
    // Set badge background color, text color, and position adjustment
    itemAppearance.normal.badgeBackgroundColor = .systemRed
    itemAppearance.normal.badgeTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    itemAppearance.normal.badgePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 1, vertical: -1)
}
```

I want a tab bar like app store but with this code I am getting it.
[image]

Comment: The App Store appears to be using a pretty standard Apple tab bar. Your screenshot looks a lot like your phone is in dark mode... is that the only difference?

Comment: already using light mode.
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
        }
    }

Comment: @RatneshPathak What do you get if the background of the view controllers in the tabs uses the same light color as the App Store?

Comment: I am getting same results. I need an app store like tab bar. please send code .

Comment: If you want the same tab bar as shown in the App Store then simply remove all of your code that attempts to modify the tab bar. By default the tab bar will look just like the App Store. No code is needed. The only requirement is that the background of the view controllers shown in each tab needs to be set to the desired background color which is `.systemBackground`. In light mode that is the light gray color you want.